# How to print the structure of a table and its contents in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, printing

I've created a simple database using Oracle SQL (iSQL plus).  How can I print the table structure and its contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the `desc` command:

http://www.riteshmandal.com/oracle.htm

> DESC or DESCRIBE : Used to describe
>   the table structure present in the
>   tablespace.
>
> USE : DESC   e.g. DESC
>   Employee;
>
> USE : SELECT * FROM  to
>   view all the data inside the table.
>   e.g. SELECT * FROM Employee

Example:

```
SQL> -- create demo table
SQL> create table Employee(
  2    ID                 VARCHAR2(4 BYTE)         NOT NULL,
  3    First_Name         VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  4    Last_Name          VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  5    Start_Date         DATE,
  6    End_Date           DATE,
  7    Salary             Number(8,2),
  8    City               VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  9    Description        VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
 10  )
 11  /

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> desc Employee;
 Name           Null?    Type
-------------------------------------------
 ID            NOT NULL   VARCHAR2(4)
 FIRST_NAME               VARCHAR2(10)
 LAST_NAME                VARCHAR2(10)
 START_DATE               DATE
 END_DATE                 DATE
 SALARY                   NUMBER(8,2)
 CITY                     VARCHAR2(10)
 DESCRIPTION              VARCHAR2(15)

SQL>
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> -- clean the table
SQL> drop table Employee
  2  /

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks,that was very informative. Is there a way to export that as a print-friendly version?

Comment: Not that I know of. Doesn't your tool have a menu item to print? I see that you're using iSQL Plus that is web based right? So it runs inside the browser... Hitting the print menu option of the browser should work.

Answer (score 5):

Two different queries will be used for this. The table to show the table structure is:

describe `<table_name>`;
or
describe table `<table_name>`;